# How can I find out byte's character in binary file in C?

Tags: c

I have a binary file, the file has char,float,integer long integer and double.

Records in the file (in the real binary file all data will be binary and there will not be any spaces or newlines):

'l' 9.8 5.64 1 8 '0' ...

and I'm wondering that how can I learn type of first byte, second byte...
(I mean it should say me : first byte is a char, second byte is a float, third byte is a double... )

Comment: Please add some code to your question !

Comment: Without already knowing something about what's in the file, you really can't tell.  It's like saying, "I heard someone count to 5... how can I tell what they were counting?"

Answer (score 4):

A byte is just a number between `0` and `255`. It doesn't have a type. `char`, `int`, `float` and other types are different ways to interpret the value(s) of one or more adjacent bytes.

For example, interpreted as `char`, the value of `65` is `A`. But when you read a byte from a file there is no way to tell it if it's the number `65` or the character `A`. It can also be one byte from a two-bytes integer number (and you have to also read the next byte to get the entire number).

Your code is the one that decides how to interpret the data.

Comment: To add to this, in order to decide, we need to know the code for the _writer_ of the file [or a specification of the file's format], and use those as a guide